# R: Combination of Anova-test (aov), for-Loop and paste results in error

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, anova

I've built a for-loop for conducting Anova-tests for a set of dependent and independent variables. In order to loop over these variables, which are all located in my dataframe `main`, I've created two vectors with dependent and independent variables (`DependentVariablesAnova` and `IndependentVariablesAnova`respectively).

I also incorporated the paste-function in order to name the resulting tests accordingly.

```
for(i in 1:length(DependentVariablesAnova)){
  for(j in 1:length(IndependentVariablesAnova)){
    paste("Anova", c(DependentVariablesAnova[i]), c(IndependentVariablesAnova[j])) <- aov(c(DependentVariablesAnova[i]) ~ c(IndependentVariablesAnova[j]), data = main)
  }
}
```

The abovementioned code results in the following error message:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" :
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I'm assuming there is a rather simple quick fix to my problem. If that is not the case and a working sample is needed, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I don't know what the `aov` function does, but for sure doing something like `paste(...) <- ... ` will not work. The `paste(..)` call returns a character vector (concataination of its arguments), so you cannot assign something to it!

Comment: Please provide example data and show your expected output (is it the `summary`/`tidy` version of `aov` output?).  See [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses `map` from the `purrr` package.
You can also use the same approach in base R with `apply`, if you prefer, although it makes tagging the DVs a little harder.

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_df(dvs, function(dv) {
  map_df(ivs, function(iv) {
    frm <- as.formula(paste(dv, "~", iv))
    aov(frm, data = main) %>% broom::tidy(.)
  })
}, .id = "dv")
```

Output

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  dv    term         df  sumsq meansq statistic p.value
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 w     x             2  1.53   0.764     0.827  0.440 
2 w     Residuals    97 89.6    0.923    NA     NA     
3 w     z             2  3.54   1.77      1.96   0.146 
4 w     Residuals    97 87.5    0.903    NA     NA     
5 y     x             2  5.49   2.74      3.13   0.0481
6 y     Residuals    97 85.0    0.876    NA     NA     
7 y     z             2  0.992  0.496     0.538  0.586 
8 y     Residuals    97 89.5    0.923    NA     NA
```

Data:

```r
n <- 100
main <- tibble(w = rnorm(n), 
               x = sample(letters[1:3], n, replace = TRUE) %>% as.factor,
               y = rnorm(n),
               z = sample(letters[4:6], n, replace = TRUE) %>% as.factor)

dvs <- c("w", "y") %>% set_names()
ivs <- c("x", "z")
```